# PostgreSQL on MacOSX

Tags: python, database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I just wanted to install a PostgreSQL Database. After 3 hours of trying I do not know what else to do. My last try included installing PostgreSQL via Homebrew -> Works perfectly fine.
But typing this:

```
which psql
```

I got this: `/usr/local/bin/psql`
From my view this sort of Path is wrong, a I saw a different one in most tutorials. But I have no idea what to do.

But I went on trying:

```
createuser -U postgres yrkIO -P
```

And the terminal asked me for a password only to give me this:

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

What can I do, I just want to run a PostgreSQL on my Python Flask App?

Comment: http://postgresapp.com

Comment: You're giving us the last part of a long story. Explain the whole thing - what you've done, from the start. What you've tried. Why you did different things, what didn't work.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/psql`: _From my view this sort of Path is wrong_: no it's correct for homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without forcing a password?

```
createuser -s -r postgres
```

This worked for me. 
Also, remember to start a server 
Start:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Stop server:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Comment: No, does not seem to work properly. I was able to create a user (i guess, there was no error but also no good feedback) and I was also able to start a server but as I wanted to stop it the terminal gave me an error asking if a server was running anyways. "PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid" does not exist"